# How a multiplier will be implemented with LUT?

Tags: fpga, multiplier

How a multiplier will be implemented with LUT(LookUp Table) or with optical LUT?.... I know how the full-adder implemented with LUT and OLUT.

Comment: https://www.altera.com/content/dam/altera-www/global/en_US/pdfs/literature/an/an306.pdf

Answer (score 1):

A multiplier is basically a series of shifters, AND gates and adders.

Start with an accumulator of 0.

- If bit 0 of the second operand is set, add the first operand, shifted left by 0.
- If bit 1 of the second operand is set, add the first operand, shifted left by 1.
- ...

If you want a non-clocked design, you need to create lookup tables for all different shift counts, which is obviously fairly resource-intensive, even after optimizing the design by combining operations and flattening the hierarchy, so many FPGA fabrics contain fixed multiplier blocks.

Answer (score 0):

The basic multiply operation on two one-bit numbers is the logical AND.  Extending this to multiple bits involves lots of AND gates and an adder tree.  The operation works exactly the same way that you would multiply on paper by one digit at a time, inserting the proper number of zeros on the right, and then adding it all up.  In binary, the partial products are either zero or a bit-shifted copy of one of the operands, masked by the corresponding bit in the other operand.  The partial products can either be computed one at a time with a shift register, or in parallel with an array of AND gates.  The partial products are then added with a set of adders called an adder tree.  Both the partial product generation and the adder tree can be optimized significantly.  More complex partial product generation schemes can cut down the number of partial products by considering more than one bit at a time.  The adder tree can be built with carry-save and carry-lookahead adders to increase parallelism.  Small components of all of these schemes would be implemented on LUTs (such as the AND gates, adders, etc), but a large number of LUTs would be required to implement a complete multiplier.  Since multipliers can take up a very large amount of logic resources and require many levels of logic, hard multipliers are included on many FPGAs to improve performance.

Comment: I can implement AND-Gate or other logical gates with (O)LUT, and I can implement FullAdder/HalfAdder too, and I also implemented 2-bit multiplier using truth table of 2-bit multiplier(4-4-OLUT...4 inputs a1a0 b1b0 and 4 outputs S3 S2 S1 S0), but How I can make an OLUT that can use the OLUTs of the partial products . In the other word, for add of partial products of (S1=a1b0+a0b1), I want use both ANDGate and HalfAdder, But How?
Its better to use this way or use shift register?

Comment: What is an OLUT?

Comment: Optical LookUp Table, an optical core implementation of LUT that uses microring resonators.